# how to display the length of a FULLNAME

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames

```
how can i get the length of the full path of a filename?
```

I am getting all the files recursively in a directory structure succesfully, and now I am trying to get the length of the fullpath:

```
get-childitem y:\ -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
select-object FullName, LastWriteTime, $($_.fullname).length | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path file.csv
```

my issue is with this: `$($_.fullname).length`:

```
Select-Object : Null parameter. Expecting one of the following types: {System.String, System.Management.Automation.Scri ptBlock}. At line:2 char:14
+ select-object <<<<  FullName, LastWriteTime, $($_.fullname).length | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -pa th file.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

**how would i get the length of the fullname of the file?**

Comment: What is the issue with `$($_.fullname).length`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i've included the issue with that. robert, i didnt know you answered powershell questions!!

Comment: @RobertHarvey cool! how did you know how to format it, then?

Comment: Hm?  The `{}` button above the editor window.

Comment: super cool!! you da man!

Comment: what does your character mean?

Comment: It's the Chinese symbol for "beauty."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom expression in the select cmdlet. Like this:

```
get-childitem y:\ -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
select-object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{n="FullNameLength";e={ $_.fullname.length }} |
export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path file.csv
```

`n` = name and `e` = expression. You can also use their full name. `l` or `label` is an alternative to `name`. No mather which way you write them, you end up with a custom property. : )

Comment: wonderful!! thank you so much!!! why were we not able to just use $_.fullname.length

Comment: because `select` needs a property-name. `$_.fullname.length` and `fullname.length` is not a property name. `$_` is an object, so `$_.fullname.length` is a command. That's why we use custom expressions

Comment: haven't read any. I've read som basic c# tutorials to understand the logic (if, when, for-loops, objects, etc.), then supplied it with stuff from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx  (the getting started + related links). At last, I've read and answered questions here on StackOverflow to get some challenges.

Comment: awesome! thanks again for the help!! what do you usually use powershell for?

Comment: ex. scripts to maintain my hyper-v lab, and misc. tasks like renaming many files using a pattern, getting specific content from files, testing simple c# code and libraries.. but this isn't relevant to the question, so I won't answer anymore here. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29941/discussion-between---and-graimer)